# Calculate difference of the records in a same column

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a table as below.

```
DATE        DIVISION            KPI      ACTUAL
01-07-2014  HYDRO       1   100
01-07-2014  HYDRO       2   200
01-07-2014  HYDRO       3   300
01-07-2014  HYDRO       4   400
01-07-2014  THERMAL     1   500
01-07-2014  THERMAL     2   600
01-07-2014  THERMAL     3   700
01-07-2014  THERMAL     4   800
```

My requirements is as below.

```
WHEN KPI IS 1, THEN ACTUAL.
WHEN KPI IS 2, THEN DIVIDE KPI 2/KPI 1 OF ACTUAL.   200/100 =2 
WHEN KPI IS 3, THEN DIVIDE KPI 4/ KPI 3 OF ACTUAL.  400/300 = 1.33
WHEN KPI IS 4, THEN ACTUAL.
```

The above calculation is same for each division.

Please give your value suggestions to write SQL to achieve the requirements.

Thanks,
Raj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CASE WHEN KPI IN (1, 4) THEN ACTUAL
     WHEN KPI = 2 THEN KPI / MIN(CASE WHEN KPI = 1 AND KPI <> 0 THEN ACTUAL END) 
                             OVER (PARTITION BY DATE, DIVISION)
     WHEN KPI = 3 THEN KPI / MIN(CASE WHEN KPI = 3 AND KPI <> 0 THEN ACTUAL END) 
                             OVER (PARTITION BY DATE, DIVISION)
END
```

You might have to change the PARTITION BY, but it looked like you want the calculation for each DATE/DVISION combination.

Answer (score 0):

You want a case statement along with getting the various `kpi` values.  I would do that using analytic functions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when kpi = 1 then actual
             when kpi = 2 then actual / actual1
             when kpi = 3 then actual / actual4
             when kpi = 4 then actual
        end)
from (select t.*,
             max(case when kpi = 1 then actual end) over (partition by date, division) as actual1,
             max(case when kpi = 4 then actual end) over (partition by date, division) as actual4
      from table t
     ) t
```